# How to get all children templates of django parent template (file name, modification)?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to know children templates on which depend on parent template in Django. I need to know all filenames or modification dates. How can I check it in Django.

For example children like `{% extend %}`, `{% include %}` and so on.

Comment: Short answer: not possible. Long answer: Wojtek Szkutnik's answer below is the closest you can get.

Answer (score 2):

Since {% extends %} and {% include %} accept also variables as parameters, **there is no bulletproof way of generating a template inheritance tree unless those variables have deterministic values**. After all, those variable values can change in a way that the code can't predict.

If you're using only static extends and includes, then I imagine a regular text search is your best friend. You can do:

```
find . -name "*.html" -print | xargs grep "{% extends "
```

in your project folder to generate a list of all extends tags, and then later you just need to parse the output. Same for the include tag.

For a different solution, I imagine you could add some debugging code in the Django template engine and traverse the whole site or specific pages - this way you could build such a tree, but only for views and conditions that you define.

Comment: You have not right here since I asked different question. I want to know all nested {% extends %} and {% include %} (file name, modification). Not want to know what will be if I will apply variables - what is also deterministic but less and need much complex solution - I want to learn file dependencies only.

Comment: Some things can be also temporarily deterministic for example 15 minutes or 1h - they not deterministic forever.

Comment: OK, let me rephrase the variables part: there is no way to generate that tree if you're using variables in {% extends %} and {% include %} (so for example, if you do {% extends logged_in_layout %}), unless you define possible sets of values for these variables.

Comment: And if you're using static values such as {% extends 'logged_in_layout.html' %} the easiest way would be a regular text search. You're looking only for a very specific pattern (two template tags) in a specific kind of files (templates), so you can just write a script which finds all of those tags and later builds a tree.

Comment: More specifically:

find . -name "*.html" -print | xargs grep "{% extends "

in the home folder of your project should do the trick for extends.

Also - if you want to find templates used for a specific page, you can use the django-debug-toolbar, which shows you a list for the current request.

Comment: indead some things can be dynamical but variable after loading template is set ...so if change it can be redraw again.